# Chrome inspector show intrinsic size of image 1x1 when the real size of image is 300x250

Tags: google-chrome, inspector

My website have some banner ads used by image (jpg,png, gif). Some of them do not display. When I inspect them by Chrome inspector and hover on the image src, the inspector show intrinsic size of images are 1x1. I open that link in the new tab, I do not see anything, but when I reload the page, the image appear. Have anyone had this problem?